# Create duplicate Linked List with given Linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

**Problem**
You are given a single (given : head, last element->next = NULL) linked list with NEXT pointer and RANDOM pointer as the attribute of LL node.

```
struct node {
  node *NEXT;
  node *RANDOM;
}
```

Now you have to duplicate this LL (Only C code)

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Why don't you show us some code that you have tried, and tell us what problems you faced with it.

Comment: Not Homework, but I was just reading few online post and tried to get the effective ans.
I tried to insert new node in between two original node
Original LL : Head -> n1 -> n2 -> ...
newHead -> head -> new1 -> n1 -> new2 -> n2....

Then Just capturing New nodes coping the RANDOM link also.
I want to know if anybody have better idea to get it done with ease.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving a straight forward solution to copy the linked list node by node.

Let say you have a linked list like this, **HEAD -> Node1 -> Node2 -> ... NodeN -> NULL**.

```
struct node * head_dup = NULL; //Create the head of the duplicate linked list.
struct node * tmp1 = head, * tmp2 = head_dup; //tmp1 for traversing the original linked list and tmp2 for building the duplicate linked list.
while( tmp1 != NULL)
{
    tmp2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Allocate memory for a new node in the duplicate linked list.
    tmp2->RANDOM = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Not sure what you are storing here so allocate memory to it and copy the content of it from tmp1.
    *(tmp2->RANDOM) = *(tmp1->RANDOM);
    tmp2->NEXT = NULL; //Assign NULL at next node of the duplicate linked list.
    tmp2 = tmp2->NEXT; //Move both the pointers to point the next node. 
    tmp1 = tmp1->NEXT;
}
```